# Two line caption positioning in subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I am using `subfigure` environment. One of the images has 2 line caption. Below is the sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfigure[One line caption]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  }
  \subfigure[Little longer caption takes over 2 lines]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  }
  \subfigure[One line caption]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  }
  \caption{Various example images}
  \label{fig:example_images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Plese see below the screenshot of generated PDF:
[image: Screenshot of generated PDF]

The middle figure has two line caption. Notice that the second line starts just below from the caption numbering. I want the second line to start below from the first line, as shown in the modified picture below:
[image: Screenshot of the desired PDF]

Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `hang` option. But, please, don't use `subfigure` in new documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfigure[One line caption]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  }
  \subfigure[Little longer caption takes over 2 lines]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  }
  \subfigure[One line caption]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
  }
  \caption{Various example images}
  \label{fig:example_images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note also the added `%` characters, to avoid spurious spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Please note that the `subfigure` package is deprecated. (Actually, it's been deprecated for quite a few years.) It should no longer be employed. Use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Here's a solution that uses the `subcaption` package, its `\subcaptionbox` macro, and the package option `format=hang`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \subcaptionbox{One line caption\label{fig:a}}%
  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \hspace{\fill}
  \subcaptionbox{Slightly longer caption occupies 2 lines\label{fig:b}}%
  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \hspace{\fill}
  \subcaptionbox{One line caption\label{fig:c}}%
  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

  \caption{Various example images}\label{fig:example_images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I totally agree with you, however, I have many `subfigure` inside the article. This time, I just posted one. Can you please suggest the workaround for `subfigure` environment, which doesn't affect other `subfigure`?